# How to hide the "! NEW" tag on a sharepoint list without affecting lists contained in the site?

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

Does anybody know if it is possible to hide the "NEW" label that gets appended to the Title field of a new SharePoint list item?

I have a nightly script that copies a list from one site to another site list and don't need the NEW to show up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to remove them image from a single view or page rather than every list in the web application what you can use the favourite tool of S[harePoint UI hackers everywhere - the Content Editor Web Part (CEWP)](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/category/scripted-solutions/content-editor-web-part/) along with javascript/jquery/css.

In this case its easy, only CSS required.

**For SharePoint 2010**

The New image is displayed as so

```
<IMG class="ms-newgif" title="New" alt="New" src="/_layouts/1033/images/new.gif">
```

So if you add the following style into a CEWP (you have to use the HTML Source View, rather than the Rich Text Editor).

```
<style>
  IMG.ms-newgif {display:none;}
</style>
```

The New image will be hidden.

**WSS3 and SharePoint 2007**

The CSS is a little more complex

```
<style>
    TABLE.ms-unselectedtitle TD.ms-vb IMG {display:none;}
    TABLE.ms-selectedtitle TD.ms-vb IMG {display:none;}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan! I'll try this first thing Monday

Comment: I added TABLE.ms-selectedtitle TD.ms-vb IMG {display:none;} to make the mouse over NEW disappear as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the value of [days-to-show-new-icon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287681(office.12).aspx) property to 0. However, this affects entire Web site; you cannot do it only for selected lists.

More information: [How to stop the !New tag from appearing when you add items to your SharePoint Team Services and SharePoint Services Web site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/825510)

Comment: Thanks Marek, I thought that would be the case, my request is a bit custom... Cheers

Comment: @Luke Hutton What do you mean? How does your script work? The SPListItem.SystemUpdate method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.systemupdate.aspx that allows to update list items without changing the Modified or Modified By fields might help.

Comment: SystemUpdate only allows you to not set modified by/date fields but the New icon is triggered by the Created Date - I guess the OP's sync routine is deleting everything and copying in afresh.

Comment: My syncing routine does delete everything first and then adds new items to keep it simple, I may look into an Update routine or try Ryan's CSS suggestion